# How to create new column in first dataframe based on the second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

i have 2 dataframe, i need to create the new columns based on the second datfarame. I can directly do using the transpose and create the column one by one but I need some efficient solution as I have many values in second data frame in the real dataset.

Here is how my df1 looks:

```
Brand      Model
A           MA
B           MB
C           MC
D           MD
```

df2

```
Channels      Values
CNN           20%
BBC           70%
TNT           10%
```

I would like the final output like this:

```
 Brand      Model        Channel-CNN       Channel-BBC        Channel-TNT
    A           MA            20%                70%               10%
    B           MB            20%                70%               10%
    C           MC            20%                70%               10%
    D           MD            20%                70%               10%
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
# transpose df2 and promote `Channels` to column names
s = df2.set_index(['Channels']).T.add_prefix('Channels-')

df1[s.columns] = np.vstack([s.values]*len(df1))
```

Output:

```
  Brand Model Channels-CNN Channels-BBC Channels-TNT
0     A    MA          20%          70%          10%
1     B    MB          20%          70%          10%
2     C    MC          20%          70%          10%
3     D    MD          20%          70%          10%
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am getting error once I run the second line of the code. `KeyError: "None of [Index([`